# Do I use promises correctly?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

I'm working on a school project right now, I want to use promises for my "matching functions" but apparently I'm doing this wrong. 
I have a dating website where users can meet other people and "match" with them. This is the idea. I'm doing a suggestion thing so it will suggest profiles automatically. So far, I can suggest people for 'straight users' but here i'm trying to do it for 'bi users' and I can't make it work.

I have a function called `getPotentialsLocation()`, it works perfectly if i'm giving it my table of 'straight users' (`straightPotentials`) but it can get into my other condition (`else if (biPotentials)`)

Why ? Everyone around me tried but we can't find any answer.

So if I'm trying to get 'straight users' it will return me the rows with the location and everything. If I'm trying to 'bi users' it will block because it can't get into the other condition event though I can `console.log(biPotentials)` all the way up.

I hope my code makes sense, if it doesn't please tell me. Because I'm going to link a lot of code here

```
router.post('/matchaSearch', function (req, res) {
 var username = session.uniqueID;
 var searcherInfos = {};
 var straightPotentials = [];
 var biPotentials = [];

 function suggestUsers(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    var query = 'SELECT sex, orientation FROM usersinfo WHERE username = ?';
    connection.query(query, [username], (err, rows, fields) => {
      connection.release()
      return err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows)
    })
  })
 })
}

suggestUsers()
.then((rows) => {
  searcherInfos = rows;
  if (searcherInfos[0].sex === 'm' && searcherInfos[0].orientation === 's'){
    console.log("searcher is straight");
    lookForSF()
      .then((rows) => {
        if (rows) {
          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            straightPotentials.push(rows[i].username)
          }
          if (straightPotentials){
            console.log("straightPotentials" + straightPotentials);
            getPotentialsLocation()
            .then((rows) => {
              console.log(rows);
            }).catch((err) => {
              throw err;
            })
          }
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
      throw err;
      });


  } else if ((searcherInfos[0].sex) && searcherInfos[0].orientation === 'b'){
    console.log("searcher is bi");
    lookForbothCauseImB()
      .then((rows) => {
        if (rows) {
          for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            biPotentials.push(rows[i].username)
          }
          if (biPotentials){
            console.log("biPotentials" + biPotentials);
            getPotentialsLocation()
            .then((rows) => {
              console.log(rows);
            }).catch((err) => {
              throw err;
            })
          }
        }
      }).catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      })
    }

//this is the .catch for my first function (suggestUsers())
}).catch((err) => {
  throw err;
})



function lookForSF(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      var query = 'SELECT username FROM usersinfo WHERE sex = "f" AND orientation = "s" AND username != ?';
      connection.query(query, [username], (err, rows, fields) => {
        connection.release()
        return err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows)
      })
    })
  })
}


function lookForbothCauseImB(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      var query = 'SELECT username FROM usersinfo WHERE sex = "f" OR sex = "m" AND orientation = "s" OR orientation = "b" AND username != ?';
      connection.query(query, [username], (err, rows, fields) => {
        connection.release()
        return err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows)
      })
    })
  })
}


function getPotentialsLocation(){
  if (straightPotentials) {
    var string = '('
    for (var i =0; i <straightPotentials.length - 1; i++){
      string += '\'' + straightPotentials[i] + '\', ';
    }
    string += '\'' + straightPotentials[straightPotentials.length - 1] + '\')';
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM userlocation WHERE username IN ' + string;
        console.log("this is our query " + query);
        connection.query(query, (err, rows, fields) => {
          connection.release();
          return err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows)
        })
      })
    })
  } else if (biPotentials) {
    var string = '('
    for (var i =0; i <biPotentials.length - 1; i++){
      string += '\'' + biPotentials[i] + '\', ';
    }

    string += '\'' + biPotentials[biPotentials.length - 1] + '\')';
    console.log("this is string" + string);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        var query = 'SELECT * FROM userlocation WHERE username IN ' + string;
        console.log("this is our query " + query);
        connection.query(query, (err, rows, fields) => {
          connection.release();
          return err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows)
        })
      })
    })
  }
 }
})
```

Comment: I suggest fixing the code highlighting.

Comment: it seems to me like you are always testing straightPotentials (which is always true as it is `[]`), and therefore the conditional on biPotentials is not evaluated: `function getPotentialsLocation(){
  if (straightPotentials) {//...} 
  else if (biPotentials) {//...}
 }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you suppose, you don't.

the mistake is **nested promises** anti-pattern (google it)

Your piece of code is huge and need a massive refactor to be set in the right way

Here you are

```
function query (pool, sql, values) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      var query = sql
      connection.query(query, values, (err, rows) => {
        connection.release()
        err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows)
      })
    })
  })
}

function suggestUsers (pool, username) {
  return query(pool, 'SELECT sex, orientation FROM usersinfo WHERE username = ?', [username])
}

function lookForSF (pool, username) {
  return query(pool, 'SELECT username FROM usersinfo WHERE sex = "f" AND orientation = "s" AND username != ?', [username])
}

function lookForbothCauseImB (pool, username) {
  return query(pool, 'SELECT username FROM usersinfo WHERE sex = "f" OR sex = "m" AND orientation = "s" OR orientation = "b" AND username != ?', [username])
}

function getPotentialsLocation (pool, potentials) {
  var usernames = potentials.map((potential) => {
    return "'" + potential + "'"
  })
  return query(pool, 'SELECT * FROM userlocation WHERE username IN (' + usernames.join(',') + ')')
}

function matchaSearch (pool, username) {
  return suggestUsers(pool, username)
      .then((searcherInfos) => {
        if (searcherInfos[0].sex === 'm' && searcherInfos[0].orientation === 's') {
          return lookForSF(pool, username)
        } else if ((searcherInfos[0].sex) && searcherInfos[0].orientation === 'b') {
          return lookForbothCauseImB(pool, username)
        }
      })
      .then((rows) => {
        var potentials = rows.map((row) => {
          return row.username
        })
        console.log('potentials' + potentials)
        return getPotentialsLocation(pool, potentials)
      })
}

router.post('/matchaSearch', function (req, res) {
  matchaSearch(pool, session.uniqueID)
    .then((results) => {
      console.log('result', results)
      res.send(JSON.stringify(results))
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('error', err)
      res.status(500).send('something wrong')
    })
})
```

Comment: I kinda understand what is the problem but I can't find anyone around me at school that knows how to it. Could you help me to structure it and avoiding this nested problem as well ?

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, I'm also trying to fix it on my side with my mates. So if you have a solution it will help a lot of people at school as well !

Comment: I see anti patterns here still - for example why does `getPotentialsLocation()` create a new promise when it could just `return query(...)` ?

Comment: likewise for `matchaSearch`

Comment: @simone.sanfratello also don't forget that a single expression arrow function (without braces) has an implicit return, e.g. `var potentials = rows.map(row => row.username)`

Comment: @simone.sanfratello Hi ! Sorry for my late answer (finals at school)
Anyway, I've tried it, I can't make it to work. I keep having `pool.getConnection is not a function`, I don't get it why.

Comment: @pkerckho retry, I've updated the code, sorry I miss to pass pool to ````suggestUsers````

Comment: Yes, i've fixed it during the night it was right in front of me. Anyway it works like a charm, I was able to get all my values for every one in the db. it feels good ! Thank you very much, I've learned a lot with this. 
Now I have to deal with this front side with pug. Im going to send it like this `.then((results) => {
      console.log('result', results)
      res.results = (JSON.stringify(results))
      res.render('userMatch', res)`

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two places where you have functions within a `.then` chain that do not return anything.

This will break the promise chain.

See e.g.:

```
lookForbothCauseImB().then(...)
```

and

```
getPotentialsLocation().then(...)
```

both of which appear to need a `return` in front of them.

Comment: I don't get it, it means I need to return something from my `lookForbothCauseImB() ` function ? I already do it it returns my rows from my query. Do I get this wrong ?

Comment: no, I'm saying that because that line above appears _inside_ a `.then` callback, it must also `return`, i.e. `return lookForbothCauseImB().then(...)`

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't get it. I started javascript 3 month ago so it's still pretty new.